# Python-libnotify showing weird behaviour with xfce4-notifyd and notify-osd

Tags: 12.04, notification, notify-osd, libnotify, python-2.7

I am trying to play with libnotify's `python bindings`. I got [this code](http://pastie.org/4181931) from `/usr/share/doc/python-notify/examples` and it is showing different behaviour with `xfce4-notifyd` and `notify-osd`.

**Case-1 with xfce4-notifyd**

[image]

**Case-2 with notify-osd**

[image]

You can see the difference in both the cases. In 1st case the `action` is integrated in the form of `button` in `xfce4-notifyd` whereas in 2nd case this is not happening. In 2nd case it just shows up as a `new window`.

So, can anyone tell me why I am observing this weird behaviour and how do I add action buttons to `notify-osd` notifications.

PS: I am using the `patched` version of notify-osd. My default notifications with notify-osd looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notify-osd does not handle actions. This is an explicit design decision by the developers. As [the design spec states](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Interaction), "Other than that hover effect, bubbles should not directly respond to input devices in any way." The [it also asserts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#alert) that when actions are requested, it will fallback to an alert box:

> For cases where applications have expected the notification system to
>   allow interactivity without checking whether it actually does, and
>   cases where applications have expected the notification system to
>   display a notification indefinitely, Notify OSD should show an alert
>   box as a fallback.

While it's up for debate whether or not that is a good decision,
Notify-osd is an implementation of the [Freedesktop notification spec](http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/docs/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html#backwards-compat),
which clearly states that it is the responsiblity of the client
to make sure the server supports the desired ability:

> Clients should try and avoid making assumptions about the presentation
>   and abilities of the notification server. The message content is the
>   most important thing.
>
> Clients can check with the server what capabilities are supported
>   using the GetCapabilities message.

You can test for notification server capabilities with something like:

```py
import pynotify

pynotify.init("Test Capabilities")
caps = pynotify.get_server_caps()

if caps and 'actions' in caps:
    # We support actions, so add a button.
    notification = pynotify.Notification("Can we use actions?", \
                                         "Yup, we sure do.")
    notification.add_action("ignore", "Ignore", ignore_cb)
else:
    notification = pynotify.Notification("Can we use actions?", \
                                         "Nope, we don't support actions.")
notification.show()
```